# Querying data from HBase directly into Spark as an RDD, or through Phoenix as a Dataframe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to query stored data that resides in HBase for use of Spark ML within AWS EMR.  Should I pull the data as an RDD(as attempted below), or should I use Phoenix to try an query the data in as a Dataframe?

I have attempted both pulling in data into Spark via HBase RDD and through Phoenix.  However I have ran into complications with both methods.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HColumnDescriptor, HTableDescriptor } 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ HBaseAdmin, Put, Result, HTable } 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.rdd.{ PairRDDFunctions, RDD } 
import org.apache.spark.streaming._ 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseGet").setMaster("local[2]")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val tableName = "test_hbase2"

System.setProperty("user.name", "hdfs")
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs")
conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost")
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, "row1");
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, "row2");

conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/conf/hbase-site.xml"))

println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
```

Upon execution, I do not get any output, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location for replica 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hive table on top of Hbase table and query from spark as below -

```
val hbasetable_df = spark.sql(s""" select * from ${hive-db}.${hive-hbase-tablename} """)
```

The above statement will create a dataframe for you which you can further change to rdd or register temp table and continue writing other SQL transformations if applicable.

I hope this will help.